How to NDSolve a PDE that contains the integral of the solution?
I would like to solve the following Fokker-Plank equation
s = Integrate[v* p[v, t], {v, -10, 10}]
u = (a - b *v^2)*v + c*s
eq = D[p[v, t], t] == - D[u*p[v, t], v] + 
   d* Laplacian[p[v, t], {v}]/2

with
i[v_] := PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], v]
sol = NDSolveValue[{eq  , p[v, 0] == i[v], p[-10, t] == 0, 
    p[10, t] == 0}, 
  p, {v, -10, 10}, {t, 0, 500}]

However, s contains the integral of p[v,t], the solution, and I have some indication that the above code doesn't do what I intended for it to do (some none-sensical results). I'm quite sure that the issue is with the fact that the variable v in the definition of s. So to get around that, I converted everything to functions:
s[t_] := Integrate[x* p[x, t], x]
u[v_, t_] := (a - b *v^2)*v + c*s[t]
eq = D[p[v, t], t] == - D[u[v, t]*p[v, t], v] + 
   d* Laplacian[p[v, t], {v}]/2

This time mathematica complained that

Delay partial differential equations are not currently supported by NDSolve.

Then I tried the trick in this question and omitted the definition of s
u[v_, t_] := (a - b *v^2)*v + c*s[t]
eq = D[p[v, t], t] == - D[u[v, t]*p[v, t], v] + 
   d* Laplacian[p[v, t], {v}]/2
sol = NDSolveValue[{eq , D[s[v, t], {v, 1}] == v * p[v, t], 
    p[v, 0] == i[v], p[-10, t] == 0, p[10, t] == 0} /. {a -> 1/5, 
    b -> 1/10, d -> 1/10, c -> 0.3}, p, {v, -10, 10}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
  Method -> molfem[0.01]]

It again complains that

Delay partial differential equations are not currently supported by NDSolve

and again gives these additional errors.

I think I am still doing things wrong.
How can I solve this PDE?

The definition of s , s[t] is unclear. Shouldn't it be s[t_] := Integrate[x* p[x, t], {x,-10,10}] ?What is the correct definition?

@UlrichNeumann thanks for the comment. In the first trial, I used s just as an expression (not as a function), and in the second trial I used as a function of t, but in both cases, s represents Integrate[x* p[x, t], {x,-10,10}]

@our the definitions u and u[t] differ too!

@UlrichNeumann I updated the question. The actual expression of u doesn't really matter as long as it contains s. the underlying problem, and my question, is how to solve the PDE when u contains s which an integral of the solution of the PDE.

We can solve this problem using method of lines as follows
i[v_] := PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], v];


h = .1; v = grid = Range[-10, 10, h]; nn = Length[grid]; M1 = 
 NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[1, grid, "DifferenceOrder" -> 4][
  "DifferentiationMatrix"]; M2 = 
 NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[2, grid, "DifferenceOrder" -> 4][
  "DifferentiationMatrix"];
P = Table[pp[i][t], {i, nn}];


d = 1; dt = .1; a = 2; b = .01; c = 1; s = 
 h  Sum[(P[[i]] v[[i]] + P[[i + 1]] v[[i + 1]])/2, {i, 1, nn - 1}];
u = (a - b*v^2)*v + c*s/(1 + (v - s)^2); eq = 
 Table[D[P[[i]], t] == -(M1 . (u  P))[[i]] + d  (M2 . P)[[i]], {i, 2, 
   nn - 1}]; bc = {D[P[[1]], t] == 0, D[P[[-1]], t] == 0}; P0 = 
 i[#] & /@ v; ic = Thread[P == P0 /. t -> 0];

sol = NDSolve[{Join[eq, bc], ic}, P, {t, 0, 10}, 
   Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}];

Visualization at different t
ListLinePlot[
 Evaluate@Table[Transpose[{v, P /. sol[[1]]}], {t, 0, 2, .2}], 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Range[0, 2, .2]]


Visualization at different v
Plot[Evaluate[Table[P[[i]] /. sol[[1]], {i, 5, nn - 5, 5}]], {t, 0, 
  4}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"t", "P"}]



Thank you Alex! much appreciatated.

@Our You are welcome!

@AlexTrounev Clever modification of bc!

@UlrichNeumann I think that we have same option in NDSolve.

@AlexTrounev My point is: You took   bc = {D[P[[1]], t] == 0, D[P[[-1]], t] == 0} instead of P[[-1]] == 0, P[[1]] == 0  (or p[-10, t] == 0, p[10, t] == 0)

@UlrichNeumann  With ic we have p[-10, t] = 0, p[10, t] = 0 automatically as solution of differential equations. This simplification commonly used in numerical methods to exclude algebraic equations. But nevertheless, NDSolve can't solve this system of ODEs without option  Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}. :)

Out of curiosity: can this "method-of-lines" be extended to solve a coupled PDEs?
If so, I'm going to ask a new question based on that

@Qur Yes, we can solve system of PDEs using this method of lines (note that this method similar to that implemented in NDSolve).
